# Fade in or out a QML Audio file?

Tags: sound, application-development, ubuntu-touch, multimedia

I have a QML Audio element in my app that plays a sound. When I click a button I execute:

```
audio.play()
```

and when I click it again I execute:

```
audio.stop()
```

Ideally I would like to fade the sound in a little when the user clicks the button to play the sound, and fade it out a little when they press the button to stop the sound.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried volume?

Comment: SoundEffect Element seems to have a volume property. Looping through it would do it, I think.

Comment: may be you can use PropertyAnimation with Audio's volume property, never tried myself though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to program QML, but here is something I found in the documentation

```
volumeCtrl.volume = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, mouse.x / (volumeBar.width - 1)));
```

Source : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-audioengine-qml-audioengine-qml.html

Answer (score 2):

Use a number or property animation.

```
NumberAnimation{ id:audiofadeout; target: audioFile; property: "volume"; from:1; to: 0; duration:1000 }
```

Then execute w/

```
audiofadeout.start()
```

﻿